# Drop row if any column value does not a obey a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe df with "1" to "x" columns and "y" number of rows. How do I drop any row where one or more column values are outside a conditional statement like greater than or less than:

I have tried this for 2 columns named "1" and "2":

```
df = df[df[["1", "2"]] < 0.02]
```

but this is giving me the same number of rows but NaN's in the column values where there used to be values.

Comment: wait i think i have figured it out df = df[(df < 0.2).all(1)] similar to another qu i asked. Still might be helpful so I have left the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
import pandas
import numpy
randn = numpy.random.randn 
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(4, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> df
      A         B         C         D
a -1.509065 -1.700310 -1.443745  0.659686
b  1.303247  0.466667 -0.320595  0.428322
c -0.126422  0.203114 -1.157571 -0.766103
d -0.611362 -0.653566  0.451102  0.617120
>>> df[~(df < 0.5).all(1)]
      A         B         C         D
a -1.509065 -1.700310 -1.443745  0.659686
b  1.303247  0.466667 -0.320595  0.428322
d -0.611362 -0.653566  0.451102  0.617120

>>> df[~(df > 1.3).any(1)]
      A         B         C         D
a -1.509065 -1.700310 -1.443745  0.659686
c -0.126422  0.203114 -1.157571 -0.766103
d -0.611362 -0.653566  0.451102  0.617120
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: even better solution based on azuric's comments